# Echart.js library for graphs (javascript) does not show data on page using xaxis type is time

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, graph

I try to show temperature on a webapge (using Echarts.js) within 24 hours based on whole hours.
I have added a sample html.doc which i try.
Somehow it does not show the data.

Here is my example code:

The staqck-overflow editor keeps complaining that i had to add more details, please view the code.
That is full code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>ECharts</title>
    <!-- including ECharts file -->
        <script src="http://echarts.baidu.com/dist/echarts.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- prepare a DOM container with width and height -->
    <div id="main" style="width: 80%;height:400px;"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        // based on prepared DOM, initialize echarts instance
        var myChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById('main'));

        var now = new Date(2019,10,7);
        var nowPlusOneday = +now + 24*3600*1000-1; 
        var data =[];

        data.push([new Date(2019,10,7,1,5),19]);        data.push([new Date(2019,10,7,2,10),34]);
        data.push([new Date(2019,10,7,3,9),12]);        data.push([new Date(2019,10,7,4,11),16]);
        data.push([new Date(2019,10,7,5,13),29]);       data.push([new Date(2019,10,7,6,16),14]);
        data.push([new Date(2019,10,7,7,45),18]);
        // specify chart configuration item and data
        var option = {
        title: {
            text: 'Temperatuur'
        },
                legend: {
                        orient: 'horizontal',
                        top: 'bottom',
                        left: 'right'
                    },        
                tooltip: {
            trigger: 'axis'
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'time',
                min: now,
            max: nowPlusOneday,
                splitNumber: 12,            
            data: data.map(function (item) {
                return item[0];
            })            
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 'dataMin',
            max: 'dataMax',
                type: 'value',
            splitLine: {
                show: true,
            },
                axisLabel: {
                    formatter: '{value} °C'
                    }
        },
        dataZoom: [{
            startValue: '2001-06-06'
        }, {
            type: 'inside'
        }],
        series: {
            name: 'Temperatuur',
            type: 'line',
            data: data.map(function (item)
            {
                return item[1];
            }),
            markLine: {
                silent: false
        }
    }

        // use configuration item and data specified to show chart
        myChart.setOption(option);
    </script></body></html>
```

This is my output:

[output of html file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f7fUE.png)

All help is welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Anand

Comment: One thing I think you'll need to fix is the fact your pushing an array rather than a value in all your data.push() calls. Strip out the [] in each of the .push()

Comment: Why should i do that?i am pushing (y,x) pairs.
x = Datetime and y = temp value on that day.

Do i have to do it in a different way?